# Google Apps Script setOwner on folder it disappears

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, permissions, google-apps

I am trying to bulk move folders from one Google Drive account to various user accounts.  I have been playing around with Google Apps Script to see if I can do this.  This is what is happening:

1. Create Test Folder in my Drive
2. From Google Apps Script, share the folder (edit rights) with another user
3. Set the other user as the owner of the folder, this sets me with edit rights
4. Remove myself from having any rights

At step 2 I am able to see the folder in the second users Drive (shared with me), but at step 3 the folder disappears from the second user all together.  Any files that were in the folder can only be found in the 'Recent' section.

Has anyone seen this?

Here is the code function (I've shortened Ids and left out usernames)

```
function folderOps(){ 
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('0ByoBlv24h2');
  folder.addEditor('username@domain.com');
  folder.setOwner('username@domain.com');
  folder.removeEditor('me@domain.com');     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's losing all parents information after transfering, just save the parents then set them again after setOwner:

```
function folderOps(){ 
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('0ByoBlv24h2'),
      parents = folder.getParents();
  folder.addEditor('username@domain.com');
  folder.setOwner('username@domain.com');

  while( parents.hasNext() )
    parents.next().addFolder(folder);

  folder.removeEditor('me@domain.com');
}
```

Or maybe after removeEditor, I haven't been able to reproduce this.

Comment: Unfortunately it is still doing the same behavior. I have walked through the code with the debugger.  At the `folder.addEditor` I can see the folder appear in the second users "shared with me". Then at `folder.setOwner` it disappears from the second users "shared with me", but stays in the original users drive with the second user as owner. It cannot be found anywhere in the second users drive.  At `folder.removeEditor` it is gone from both.  Files that were in the folder are in the second users recent section only.

Comment: My bad, it must be run as the user who got the new permission, the file should be in the root folder anyway tough. You can make a webapp published on the other user account that will arrange the file in the folder passing the ID of the file and folder as parameters.